# Show an entire function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having a bit a trouble with the following problem:

Let f be an entire function for which $|f(z^2)| \leq 3|z|^{3/2} +4$. Show f is constant.

As far as I know, I can state that $f(z^2)$ is at most a polynomial of degree $ \lfloor 3/2 \rfloor =1$. But from here I'm kinda stuck, not knowing what to do. 
Using Cauchy's integral formular for the n'th derivative doesn't really get me anywhere.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $z \in \mathbb{C}$, there is some $w$ such that $w^2 = z$, hence $$|f(z)|  = |f(w^2)| \leq 3|w|^{3/2} + 4 = 3 |z|^{3/4} + 4.$$
And this inequality is true for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Now apply the generalization of Liouville's theorem to find that $f$ is polynomial of degree at most $\lfloor 3/4 \rfloor = 0$, ie. a constant.

Comment: Would assume I could apply the same theorem to this inequality? Otherwise with Cauchy's Integral formular for the n'th derivate I can show that it $\rightarrow 0$ as $|z|=r \rightarrow \infty$..

Comment: Both approaches work; in fact they're the same, if you look at the proof of the theorem.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the help